# Move command moves the whole directory instead of a specific file in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, centos6, mv

```
/bin/mv /myhome/templocation/images/*.iso /storage/data/repository/ >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm expecting this command to move the iso in /myhome/templocation/images to /storage/data/respository.

However, what is see is different. at the end of the script the entire images folder is moved to 
`/storage/data/repository/`.

Ex: `/storage/data/repository/images/*.iso` ... But I wanted the script to copy the .iso in `/storage/data/respository/*.iso/`

Where Am I going wrong ..??  As this shell script runs during the system boot time I'm unable to debug. 
Any suggestions.

This behavior is seen on CentOs6.

Comment: You show one line of code, but you talk about a script. Is there something else you need to show us?

Comment: try just using that command; without the rest of your script.

Comment: also; you want the copy to be in `/storage/data/repository/` or in a subfolder?

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I would like to get it copied in /storage/data/repository/. I dont want any sub folder. If I try the command on shell its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

shell expansion using "*" can cause random bugs and security holes.
 It's much safer to use:

```
find ... -exec mv {} dst;
```

Like:

```
find -maxdepth 0 \            <-- do not enter subdirectories
 -type f \                    <-- just files (not links, directories)
 -name "*.iso"  \             <-- just *iso names
 /myhome/templocation/images/ <-- base dir 
 -exec mv {} /storage/data/repository/ \;   <-- {} will be replaced by each file found
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach file in(path/with/wildcards*)
do
  if [ $file -f ];                # if file
  then
    mv $file 'new/location$file'
  else
    continue                      # if subdirectory
  fi
done 

echo finished.
```